# CPP: error: the default constructor cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Tags: c++

debug.cpp

```
struct debug_buf_list
{
    int id;
    uint32 *buf;
};

struct debug_map_t 
{
   int b;
   map<uint32 index, struct debug_buf_list *> _debug_list;
};

std::atomic<debug_map_t> debug_info;
```

Compile the above code generates the error as below:

> error: the default constructor of "std::atomic<debug_map_t>" cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
> std::atomic<debug_map_t> debug_info;

Without using map, the same definition working fine.

Comment: `std::atomic` requires a trivially copyable type.

Comment: Also `std::atomic` is not transitive - that is - reads and writes to `debug_map_t::_debug_list` and it's contents will not be atomic.  So my guess is you will need a `std::mutex` to lock `debug_map_t`

Answer (score 0):

The std::atomic template requires type T to be a [TriviallyCopyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TriviallyCopyable) type. Thus you can't insatiate it for your structure because it contains std::map which has a user-defined copy constructor. The error message is probably conceived from the way this requirement was implemented. It looks like the default constructor was disabled via `enable_if` for non-trivially copyable types.